# Store CGPoint in Core Data efficiently

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to find a way to store a CGPoint in a Core Data db.

After googling around I found somewhere that one way to do it would be to have an Entity (Point2D in my case) with x and y attributes. Both floats that get mapped to NSNumber.

The problem is that in order to get the point back I have the following method of my Point2D NSManagedObject sublass:

```
- (CGPoint) cgPointValue {
    return CGPointMake([self.x floatValue], [self.y floatValue]);
}
```

And it works, but as I have a lot of points it seems to be hogging the CPU.

I wonder if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

I think there is no way to save some CPU time in this case, event with code below, it will do same thing, maybe less maybe more:

```
// >>> Saving result string int CoreData
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(20.0f, 20.f);
NSString *pointToSavae = NSStringFromCGPoint(point); // Will store string {20,20}

// >> Restoring point from string, retrieved from CoreData
CGPoint pointFromString = CGPointFromString(pointToSavae);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I kind of fixed it storing the generated CGPoint in an ivar (NSValue) and checking if it exists before re-generating it. Then on willChangeValueForKey: I set the ivar to nil. So now it only generates it when it changes.